# Inserting mx records in forward zone

Tags: linux, email, bind, mx-record, dns-zone

What is the correct way (and why) to add MX records to a forward zone using bind9?

Option A

```
@   IN MX 10 mx1.example.com.
@   IN MX 20 mx2.example.com.
mx1.example.com. IN A a.b.c.d
mx2.example.com. IN A a.b.c.d
```

Option B

```
example.com.    IN MX 10 mx1.example.com.
example.com.    IN MX 20 mx2.example.com.
mx1.example.com. IN A a.b.c.d
mx2.example.com. IN A a.b.c.d
```

Or is there another alternative?

Comment: The results would be identical.

Answer (score 5):

$ORIGIN defines a base value from which 'unqualified' name (those without a terminating dot) substitutions are made when processing the zone file. 
The <kbd>@</kbd> symbol is a short-hand for the $ORIGIN in zone files.

Using the short-hand `@` or the full name `example.com.` is therefore equivalent.

$ORIGIN can be specified explicitly in the zone file, but is often implied from the zone name as specified in the Bind configuration file:

```
// named.conf file fragment

zone "example.com" in{
    type master;
    file "example.com.zone";
};
```

and

```
; example.com.zone file fragment 
; no $ORIGIN present and is synthesized from the zone name in named.conf ==> example.com
....
@          IN      NS     ns1.example.com. 
; ns1.example.com. is the name server for example.com.
@          IN      MX 10  mx1.example.com. 
; mx1.example.com. is the primary mailserver name for example.com.    
....
$ORIGIN uk.example.com.
; explicitly define or "reset" $ORIGIN to uk.example.com.
; doing this mid-way in a zone-file is not common practice anymore (if it ever was) 
; but it will keep a large single zone-file somewhat more readable.
@          IN      NS     ns2.example.com. 
; functionally identical to
; uk.example.com. IN NS ns2.example.com
; ns2.example.com. is the name server for uk.example.com.
```

A third option, is that a line in a zone file that starts  with neither a hostname, the zone name or the <kbd>@</kbd> shorthand for the zone origin, becomes a continuation of the record above.

```
@   IN MX 10 mx1.example.com.
    IN MX 20 mx2.example.com.  ; another record for the @ record above
    IN NS    ns1.example.com.  ; yet another record for the @ record above
    IN NS    ns2.example.com.  ; and a 3rd continuation for the @ record above
```

is also equivalent to:

```
@              IN MX 10 mx1.example.com.
example.com.   IN MX 20 mx2.example.com.
               IN NS    ns1.example.com. ; NS record for the example.com. record above
                                         ; the continuation can be to set different 
                                         ; record types for the same resource record name
example.com.   IN NS    ns2.example.com.

www            IN A     10.9.8.7
               IN A     192.168.0.1      ; or set multiple (round-robin) records when 
                                         ; continuing with the same record type.
```